# Spring Kafka NewTopic TopicBuilder, --command-config option?

Tags: spring-kafka

When i create topics using `kafka-topics.bat`, i do this:

> kafka-topics.bat --bootstrap-server %host%:%port% --create --topic %%t
> --partitions %partitions% --replication-factor %replication_factor% --config max.message.bytes=%max_message_bytes% --config min.insync.replicas=%min_insync_replicas% --config
> retention.ms=%retention_ms% --command-config client.properties

I am trying to *convert* the above using Spring Kafka `TopicBuilder` introduced in 2.3. But i do not know how to *convert* the `command-config` option. Is it possible?

The rest is straight-forward as per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics):

```
@Bean
public NewTopic topic(){
    return TopicBuilder.name("topic-name")
        .partitions(x)
        .replicas(x)
        .config(TopicConfig.MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES_CONFIG, "xxx")
        .config(TopicConfig.MIN_IN_SYNC_REPLICAS_CONFIG, "xxx")
        .config(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "xxx")
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found it! In case it helps someone, here is the solution:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServers);
    configs.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    configs.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
    configs.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required " + 
                                    "username=username " + 
                                    "password=password;");
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```

Cheers